# Java Android: How to find a fragment inside navigation drawer fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I created a navigation drawer and on the top I would like to place a fragment containing information about the logged in user (kind of like what google apps have.) I made the fragment and put it inside the navigation drawer and that works fine, but I need to pass it data from the parent fragment. Thus I tried using

```
 (UserOverviewFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.user_fragment);
```

But that returns null everytime. How can I get the Fragment object?
Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need something called `RecyclerView`. Follow this [excellent guide](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html) to do it.

Comment: I am not sure how does this help me figure out how why does the above code return null. I read what you suggested, but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: @ArkayCZ I cannot possibly give you a code example without you adding any code. Recycler view is the best method for implementing what you want, and I pointed you in that direction.

Comment: OK. Well I'm going to try it out. Thanks.